# Attribute Error and HTTP Error 404 trying to scrape images from websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the images from a list of websites. However I got he following error messages:

1) AttributeError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-d786eb50d187> in <module>
     14     html = urlopen(link)
     15     bs = bs4(html, 'html.parser')
---> 16     images = bs4.find_all('img', {})
     17 
     18     for image in images:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py in find_all(self, name, attrs, recursive, text, limit, **kwargs)
   1698         :rtype: bs4.element.ResultSet
   1699         """
-> 1700         generator = self.descendants
   1701         if not recursive:
   1702             generator = self.children

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'
```

and

2) HTTP 404

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Do you know what they are and how I could fix them?

The code that I am using is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

images=[]

list_1=["file_1.csv"]

df = pd.read_csv("path"+list_1)

for link in df["Col"]:
    html = urlopen(link)
    bs = bs4(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs4.find_all('img', {})

    for image in images: 
            images.append(image['src'])
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

images=[]

list_1=["file_1.csv"]

df = pd.read_csv("path"+list_1)

for link in df["Col"]:
    try:
        html = urlopen(link)
    except Exception:
        continue 

    bs = bs4(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs4.find_all('img')

    for image in images: 
            images.append(image['src'])
```

The errors that you received was the first one of the find_all method you look it with {} that is empty and the 404 error was due to urlopen method didn't found the link that you provided.

Comment: Thank you, Leo. I noticed that there was an error in my code above. `list_1` is used in df. Link is in `df["Col"]` (rows contain links). Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: The find_all explanation helped you?

Comment: it seems clear your explanation about the find_all. However, I am getting an error when I try `html = urlopen(link[0])`: `ValueError: unknown url type: 'h'`

Comment: try only link without the [0]

Comment: A few of these urls are not available anymore and this probably is causing the issue. However, I would like to be able to scrape images from websites that are still available (if it could be possible). I do not know how to try to skip the urls above that are giving me HTTP 403 and 404 errors.

Comment: The edited code will solve it and if you want to be more explicit in the  except you can specify 404 error.